# Wicket Authorization Using MetaDataKey

Tags: authorization, wicket

I am trying to implement a simple authorization strategy for my Wicket application. I am implemented my own AuthorizationStrategy (extending IAuthorizationStrategy).

http://old.nabble.com/Authorization-strategy-help-td18948597.html
After reading the above link, I figured it makes more sense to use metadata-driven authorization than one using Annotations.

So I have a simple RoleCheck class

```
public class RoleCheck {

 private String privilege;

 public RoleCheck(String priv) {
  this.privilege = priv;
 }

 public void setPrivilege(String privilege) {
  this.privilege = privilege;
 }

 public String getPrivilege() {
  return privilege;
 }
}
```

I add it a component:

```
public static MetaDataKey<RoleCheck> priv = new MetaDataKey<RoleCheck>() {};
editLink.setMetaData(priv, new RoleCheck("Update"));
```

And in my Authorization Strategy class, I try to get the metadata associated with the component:

```
public boolean isActionAuthorized(Component component, Action action) {
  if (action.equals(Component.RENDER)) {
      RoleCheck privCheck = (RoleCheck) component.getMetaData(EditControlToolBar.priv);
      if (privCheck != null) {
           ...
      }
}
```

However the getMetaData gives an error

> "Bound mismatch: The generic method `getMetaData(MetaDataKey<M>)` of
>   type `Component` is not applicable for the arguments
>   (`MetaDataKey<RoleCheck>`). The inferred type `RoleCheck` is not a
>   valid substitute for the bounded parameter "

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RoleCheck class should implement Serializable.

And are you using Wicket 1.4 ? In which case I'd suggest proceeding this way :

```
public class RolePermissionKey extends MetaDataKey<RoleCheck> {
    public static final RolePermissionKey KEY = new RolePermissionKey();
}
```

To add it to a componenet :

```
editLink.setMetaData(RolePermissionKey.KEY, new RoleCheck("Update"));
```

And to perform the authorization :

```
RoleCheck privCheck = component.getMetaData(RolePermissionKey.KEY)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. I missed making the RoleCheck serializable! (Duh!)