# Is it possible use a metadata driven component based authorization with Wicket?

Tags: authorization, wicket

Is it possible use a metadata driven component based authorization?

*Wicket in Action* gives, as an example:

> ```
> @AdminOnly
> private class ModeLink extends Link {.....}
> ```
>
> Then implement isActionAuthorized() of the Authorization Strategy.

But I feel that it is not a good solution to create new classes for every role.

Is there a metadata-driven way to do this? Can I add some metadata to a component and then check based on that in the `isActionAuthorized()` method of the authorization strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I provided a metadata-based solution here : [Wicket Authorization Using MetaDataKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595993/wicket-authorization-using-metadatakey/2603592#2603592) in response to your question.

As for the annotations, you can use a single annotation,say @RequiresRole, parameterized with the role id : @RequiresRole("admin") for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string constants for all your roles and do:

```
@Require(MySession.ADMIN_ROLE)
public class AdminPanel extends Panel {
  // snip
}

public boolean isActionAuthorized(Component c, Action a) {
  // I usually disallow instantiation of pages and rendering of components
  if (c instanceof Page || a == Component.RENDER) {
    Require r = c.getClass().getAnnotation(Require.class);
    if (r != null && !Strings.isEmpty(r.value()) {
      Roles roles = ((AuthenticatedWebSession)Session.get()).getRoles();
      return roles != null && roles.hasRole(a.value());
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Instead of strings you could also use an enum to disallow random strings. Simply use `a.value().name()` in this case to check the role.